# Why does water in a glass ripple but oil does not?

Tags: waves, water, surface-tension

When I place a glass of water on the table and hit the table from below I can clearly see ripples in the water with their center in the middle of the glass. However when I do the same with a glass filled with oil there are no ripples. The oil seems much more stable.

Why is this? This is exactly the opposite of what I would expect. Since the water has a higher surface tension than oil I would expect the water to be more stable.

Comment: Maybe viscosity?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Ah yeah thanks. Oil has a much higher viscosity than water.

Comment: [Oil does ripple](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-oil-droplet-extreme-close-up-drop-creating-ripples-isolated-black-background-image49089237), but less and slower (from identical impact), because of high viscosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oil has a far higher viscosity than the water. Since this is a direct measure of the resistance to gradual deformation from a stress, the oil has far smaller ripples than the water for an equal forces - the ripples will also appear to propagate slower through the oil.